# Laravel 5.7 query with 3 tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm pretty new to Laravel and i got stuck with building a more complex query:

I've 3 tables with their models:

Codes:

- id
- description
- factor

  ```
  public function purposes() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Purpose', 'code_purposes', 'code_id', 'purpose_id'); 
  //I could be wrong here
  }
  ```

Purpose:

- id
- name
- description

Code_purposes:

- code_id
- purpose_id

  ```
    public function codes() {
      $this->belongsToMany('App\Code'); //I could be wrong here
  }

  public function purposes() {
      $this->belongsToMany('App\Purpose'); //I could be wrong here
  }
  ```

What I want is to fetch all the codes with the condition where the purposes name = 'some_name'

I thought this would be easy with the relationships, but I can't figure it out.

So how do I do this in Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Code` model:

```
public function purposes() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Purpose');
}
```

In `Purpose` model:

```
public function codes() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Code');
}
```

Now you can get data like:

```
$codes = Purpose::where('name', 'some_name')->first()->codes;
```

> Relation table name must be `code_purpose`. And no need any model for this table.

Source: [Laravel Many To Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but this wasn't the answer I was looking for.
Maybe I need to tell it in a other way:

I got a purpose with the name 'something' and with that purpose I want all the codes that belong to that purpose

How do I do that?

Comment: Yes, this did the trick, I only forget to add the 'return' in the relation-functions
Now I need to find the solved-button :)
But in any case thank you very much for your quick reply

Comment: You Welcome.. :)